# Xamarin Community Toolkit CameraView - Access DCIM Folder on Android

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.uwp

I am using Xamarin Community Toolkit 1.2.0 CameraView and can record video on Android and UWP. To access the video's on UWP I use Xamarin Essentials and the code below and it works fine:

`string dataDir = FileSystem.AppDataDirectory + "\\Video\\";`

However on Android the files are saved to '/data/user/0/com.CompanyName.AppName/files/DCIM' which does not seem to be accessible. The below code return the folder list but 'DCIM' is not present.

`string[] dirs1 = Directory.GetDirectories(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory);`

`/data/user/0/com.CompanyName.AppName/files/.__tools__`
`/data/user/0/com.CompanyName.AppName/files/.config`
`/data/user/0/com.CompanyName.AppName/files/.local`
`/data/user/0/com.CompanyName.AppName/files/.__override__`

Any idea's how to access the files in the 'DCIM' folder?
Any help appreciated.
Thanks
Paul.

Comment: Hi! Does the folder exist in your device? It should not need special permissions because it's inside the app folder. But you can try adding Write permissions to android?

Comment: Juan, The folder on the device is '/data/user/0/com.MyCompany.MyApp/files/DCIM' It appears this maps to 'storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.app/files/DCIM'

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it working using dependency injection.

```
namespace MyApp.Dependency
{
    public interface IGetVideo
    {
        string GetVideoAsync();
    }
}
```

```
using Android.Content;
using MyApp.Dependency;
using System.IO;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(MyApp.Droid.GetVideo))]
namespace MyApp.Droid
{
    public class GetVideo : IGetVideo
    {
        Context context = Android.App.Application.Context;
        public string GetVideoAsync()
        {
            // storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.app/files/
            Java.IO.File appStorageDir = context.GetExternalFilesDir(null);
            string appStorageDirString = appStorageDir.AbsolutePath;
            string dcimFolder = Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDcim;
            var dcimPath = Path.Combine(appStorageDirString, dcimFolder);  
            return dcimPath;     
        }
    }
}
```

```
string dcimFolderPath = DependencyService.Get<IGetVideo>().GetVideoAsync();
```